# Unable to pass/access array index through props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am fairly new to React.

I have a two function components, like a Parent and a Child within it. I am passing some `props` from Parent to the Child. The props which I am passing is basically a JSON array. I can log it in the console. The problem when I try to access it through the index it fails with error:

> Cannot read property '0' of null

Below is my code. I have mentioned in commented lines about the error.
Parent component:

```
function ProjectStages(props) {   
    const [projectStages, setProjectStages] = React.useState(null);

    let projectNumber = props.match.params.projectNumber;
    useEffect(() => {
          ProjectAPI.getProjectStages(projectNumber).then((response) => {
            console.log(response[0]);  //works fine
            setProjectStages(response);
          });
    }, []);

    return (
      <div>
        <CriteriaScores criterias={projectStages[0]}/>  // this fails, Cannot read property '0' of null
        <CriteriaScores criterias={projectStages}/>  // this works
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Child component:

```
function CriteriaScores(props) {
  console.log(props.criterias); // this works
  console.log(props.criterias[0]); // this fails, Cannot read property '0' of null

  return (
    //..
  );
}

export default CriteriaScores;
```

I tried setting the props to state using `useEffect` within the Child component and then accessing but got no luck. I can see in the React developer tools that props are having the exact data what I need. Any idea what I am doing wrong? Please let me know if I can provide more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`projectStages` will be `null` initially. Until the data arrives you probably don't want to render `<CriteriaScores />` but rather some placeholder:

```
 if(projectStages === null) 
   return <div> Loading Criterias ... </div>;

 return (
   <div> 
      <CriteriaScores criterias={projectStages} />
   </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 2):

`props.criterias` is `null` on the first render, so you need to take care of `null` in your `CriteriaScores` component or in `ProjectStages`.

Try this:

```
console.log(props.criterias && props.criterias[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you initialized your state with null:

```
const [projectStages, setProjectStages] = React.useState(null);
```

Then you making an asynchronous call:

```
ProjectAPI.getProjectStages(projectNumber).then(response => {
  console.log(response[0]); //works fine
  setProjectStages(response);
})
```

Therefore `setProjectStages(response)` will be called sometime "in the future",
meanwhile, your component got rendered with the initial value `null` and you tried to access it.

To fix it, `await` for the async call **or** *as everyone mentioned, take care or `null`*

```
async function fetchMyAPI() {
  const respone = await ProjectAPI.getProjectStages(projectNumber);
  setProjectStages(response);
}

useEffect(() => {
  fetchMyAPI();
}, []);
```